# String function task in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, string-parsing

Hi guys I'm trying to take a URL of the form

```
http://www.domainname.com/stuff/morestuff/content?extrastuff
```

And using a JavaScript string function parse out "content" based on the surrounding regular expressions "morestuff/" and "?". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c = yourString.match(/\/morestuff\/([^?]*)/)[1];
```